# What is the difference between adding the table with join or adding directly after "from"

Tags: sql

I am new in sql so i just dont know the difference between them. Does it affect compile time or something else? Can you explain it?

```
select a.name, b.salary from account a, bank b
where a.id = b.id;
```

or

```
select a.name, b.salary from account a
join bank b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.  The latter is a newer (SQL-92) syntax and easier to read.

Comment: ok, and can we write two join repeatedly? join b on blabla nextline join c on blabla

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple joins, to both the "base" table and a previously joined table